# Python: Regex for words and hyphens

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I'm using an API which until recently returned a dictionary with variables in the form of {{variable_name}}. I would then translate those variables into my own strings using a translation dictionary and this line:

```
new_string = re.sub(r"\{\{(\w+)\}\}", lambda m: translator[m.group(1)], raw_string)
```

However the API has changed, and for some odd reason now the variables are with hyphens instead of underscores, like {{variable-name}}.

Now with the hyphen my regex isn't matching, and after endless attempts to fix that and reviewing other Stack Overflow questions which failed me, I'm not sure what else I can try.

Long story short, I'm trying to match any series of word characters (letters, numbers, and underscore) and the hyphen character, surrounded by double curly brackets.

Comment: Try this regex: `"\{\{([\w-]+)\}\}"`

Comment: Well seems simple to me. Include hyphen in character class `[A-Za-z0-9_-]` Or `[\w-]`.

Comment: Are you certain the hyphens are really hyphens?  And not long dashes or some Unicode character?

Comment: @grundic 's solution did the trick! I was sure I tried that too. Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For variables in the form `{{variable_name}}` you used `\w` which is shorthand for `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.

> However the API has changed, and for some odd reason now the variables are with hyphens instead of underscores, like {{variable-name}}.

Now that `_` underscore is out of question **you should use character class `[A-Za-z0-9-]`**. Note that `-` should come at end or beginning in character class to avoid it's interpretation as range.

If there is still possibility of `_` in some cases then use `[\w-]` where `\w` is shorthand for word as mentioned above.

Hence your regex would be `\{\{([\w-]+)\}\}`